# Boost.Geometry polygon point assignment

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

i am trying to use boost geometry and having trouble assigning points to a polygon.
Lets assume i create an static vector of points

```
boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> >* a;
```

And then i create a polygon:

```
boost::geometry::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> > polygon;
```

Assuming i have already defined the values of the points of a.

How can i assign the points from a to P?

Answer (score 7):

The [`boost::geometry::assign_points()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/assign/assign_points.html) algorithm can be used to assign a range of points to a polygon.

If `a` is a range of points and `P` is a polygon, then one would use:

```cpp
boost::geometry::assign_points(P, a);
```

---

Here is a complete [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb9ca20853196220) demonstrating the usage of `assign_points`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/assign/std/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/area.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/algorithms/assign.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/dsv/write.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::assign;
    typedef boost::geometry::model::d2::point_xy<double> point_xy;

    // Create points to represent a 5x5 closed polygon.
    std::vector<point_xy> points;
    points +=
      point_xy(0,0),
      point_xy(0,5),
      point_xy(5,5),
      point_xy(5,0),
      point_xy(0,0)
      ;

    // Create a polygon object and assign the points to it.
    boost::geometry::model::polygon<point_xy> polygon;  
    boost::geometry::assign_points(polygon, points);

    std::cout << "Polygon " << boost::geometry::dsv(polygon) << 
      " has an area of " << boost::geometry::area(polygon) << std::endl;
}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Polygon (((0, 0), (0, 5), (5, 5), (5, 0), (0, 0))) has an area of 25
```

Comment: Thanks, but i had already seen that. What i have is not an std::vector, is a memoty array, a pointer.
I know that one solution would be to iterate the array, take every value and append it to the polygon, but i wanted to know if there was any way to do it more directly, like with your vector example

Comment: @user3013172 Although the example uses `std::vector`, the `assign_points()` algorithm operates on types that model the [Boost.Range concept](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/overview.html).  This [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55522720d6267b04) uses an array, and invokes `assign_points()` with a `std::pair` object constructed with an array's start and end pointer.